# How would I use Procs in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are a few helpers I am using in my project, which I just thought that I could maybe treat as Procs, as they do very specific tasks and can be used by very different components.

I've used Procs in small Ruby projects, mainly when learning the language, and I thought that this would be a good occasion to put them to use.

My question is, where would I put the Procs in the Rails folder structure? Are there any guidelines or reccomdendations for this? Is it considered good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit puzzled what the advantage would be of using Procs over using simple methods? So if you could give some examples, that would be nice.

Anyways: since Procs can be stored in a variable, I would declare a module inside the `lib` folder, and define the procs as variables, constants, or methods returning the proc. Something like this

```
module ProcContainer

  def proc_1(factor)
    Proc.new { |n| n*factor }
  end

  PROC_2 = Proc.new { |n| 2 * n }

end
```

which would be used as

```
gen_proc = ProcContainer.proc_1(6)
result = gen_proc(3)

other_proc = ProcContainer.PROC_2(4)
```

The advantage of the method is obvious i guess, since it will return a new `Proc` object every time it is called, while the constant is only evaluated once.

(of course you should change the naming to something more appropriate)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I thought that rails would have a more specific place for Procs / code blocks, but I guess that I am wrong. The case I was thinking about is an application wide filter that I want to use to apply to content before outpputing it. Right now I have it as a helper and use it in the views, but for some reason that didnt felt right, so I wanted to learn more about Proc's ...

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has amazing syntax for blocks, so we tend to favor them over explicitly making procs. The downside of blocks is that they need to be executed immediately when the called method yields to them (procs don't have that limitation). That is in place for performance reasons, but you can easily package up a block as a proc, and store it somewhere else for later, or pass it down to another method. So even though you are probably using procs every day, you don't really realize it, because your interface to them is through the block syntax.

Comment: I am aware of blocks and everything, what I meant is that I want to store Procs to pass them  to methods for very specific independent tasks, but I dont know in what file should I put them inside Rails, so they are accessible by the whole application.